# Don't able to close second window while opening the third window at same time in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.6

Please help me where is I am not getting the correct code. I want to close the second window and open the third window simultaneously but both the windows are visible to me.

I want to make an app that is very similar to an alarm app but for a spiritual organization Brahma kumaris. Please help me in making this wonderful app.
Please find below my code -

```
# DISPLAY PART
# window1
def newwindow1():
    root.destroy()
    newwindow1 = Tk()
    newwindow1.title("Traffic Control")
    newwindow1.geometry("321x475")
    newwindow1.configure(background = "black")

    on1 = PhotoImage(file = "on1.png")
    off1 = PhotoImage(file = "off1.png")

    def Hindinewwindow2():
        Hindinewwindow2 = Toplevel(newwindow1)
        Hindinewwindow2.title("Traffic Control")
        Hindinewwindow2.geometry("321x475")
        Hindinewwindow2.configure(background = "black")
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! This is a lot of code to ask someone to read through. Do you think you could provide a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that shows only the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Is `newwindow1` the *second window* and `Hindinewwindow2` the *third window*?  If yes, you cannot close the second window and keep the third window because second window is the root window.